# Reduce columns selected by EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.1

I'm using [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) to query a database.

One of the ways to reduce the amound of columns that are retrieved using EF Core is to use the select statement. For example,

```
using (SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext(connection, loggerFactory))
{
    foreach (Pupil pupil in context.Pupils.Select(pupil => new Pupil{ Id = pupil.Id, Name = pupil.Name }))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pupil.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(pupil.Age);
        Console.WriteLine(pupil.Name);
    }
}
```

will reduce

```
SELECT "p"."id", "p"."age", "p"."name"
FROM "pupil" AS "p"
```

to

```
SELECT "p"."id" AS "Id", "p"."name" AS "Name"
FROM "pupil" AS "p"
```

However, my issue is I needed a way that could do this dynamically as different columns will be selected via user choice. So I wrote a small class that could dynamically create these select statements

```
public class Selector<T>
{
    private readonly List<PropertyInfo> _properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

    public Selector<T> AddProperty<TPropertyType>(Expression<Func<T, TPropertyType>> property)
    {
        if (!(property.Body is MemberExpression member))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{property}' refers to a method, not a property.");
        }

        if (!(member.Member is PropertyInfo propertyInfo))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{property}' refers to a field, not a property.");
        }

        _properties.Add(propertyInfo);
        return this;
    }

    public Func<T, T> Select()
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        NewExpression objToInitialise = Expression.New(typeof(T));
        IEnumerable<MemberAssignment> propertiesToInitialise = _properties.Select(property =>
            {
                MemberExpression originalValue = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
                return Expression.Bind(property, originalValue);
            }
        );
        MemberInitExpression initialisedMember = Expression.MemberInit(objToInitialise, propertiesToInitialise);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(initialisedMember, parameter).Compile();
    }
}
```

and be used like

```
using (SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext(connection, loggerFactory))
{
    Func<Pupil, Pupil> pupilIdsAndNames = new Selector<Pupil>()
        .AddProperty(x => x.Id)
        .AddProperty(x => x.Name)
        .Select();

    foreach (Pupil pupil in context.Pupils.Select(pupilIdsAndNames))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pupil.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(pupil.Age);
        Console.WriteLine(pupil.Name);
    }
}
```

---

**The issue**

The issue is, the code I wrote to dynamically generate the expression does not reduce the amount of data returned from the query. The query run by EF Core is

```
SELECT "p"."id", "p"."age", "p"."name"
FROM "pupil" AS "p"
```

This can be seen in the MCVE below.

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

---

**MCVE**

*The program requires [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/) and [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/).*

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -Version 3.1.1
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console -Version 3.1.1
```

*The Code*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ExplicitLoadTest
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
            connection.Open();

            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => {
                    builder.AddConsole();
                }
            );

            Pupil phil = MakePupilWithNameAndAge("Phil", 7);
            Pupil joe = MakePupilWithNameAndAge("Joe", 8);
            Pupil mac = MakePupilWithNameAndAge("Mac", 5);
            Pupil rose = MakePupilWithNameAndAge("Rose", 10);
            Pupil harry = MakePupilWithNameAndAge("Harry", 9);
            Pupil meg = MakePupilWithNameAndAge("Meg", 8);

            using (SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext(connection, loggerFactory))
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                context.Pupils.Add(phil);
                context.Pupils.Add(joe);
                context.Pupils.Add(mac);
                context.Pupils.Add(rose);
                context.Pupils.Add(harry);
                context.Pupils.Add(meg);

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext(connection, loggerFactory))
            {
                foreach (Pupil pupil in context.Pupils.Select(pupil => new Pupil{ Id = pupil.Id, Name = pupil.Name }))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(pupil.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine(pupil.Age);
                    Console.WriteLine(pupil.Name);
                }
            }

            using (SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext(connection, loggerFactory))
            {
                Func<Pupil, Pupil> pupilIdsAndNames = new Selector<Pupil>()
                    .AddProperty(x => x.Id)
                    .AddProperty(x => x.Name)
                    .Select();

                foreach (Pupil pupil in context.Pupils.Select(pupilIdsAndNames))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(pupil.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine(pupil.Age);
                    Console.WriteLine(pupil.Name);
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }

        private static Pupil MakePupilWithNameAndAge(string name, int age) => new Pupil
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = name,
            Age = age
        };
    }

    public class Selector<T>
    {
        private readonly List<PropertyInfo> _properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        public Selector<T> AddProperty<TPropertyType>(Expression<Func<T, TPropertyType>> property)
        {
            if (!(property.Body is MemberExpression member))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{property}' refers to a method, not a property.");
            }

            if (!(member.Member is PropertyInfo propertyInfo))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{property}' refers to a field, not a property.");
            }

            _properties.Add(propertyInfo);
            return this;
        }

        public Func<T, T> Select()
        {
            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            NewExpression objToInitialise = Expression.New(typeof(T));
            IEnumerable<MemberAssignment> propertiesToInitialise = _properties.Select(property =>
                {
                    MemberExpression originalValue = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
                    return Expression.Bind(property, originalValue);
                }
            );
            MemberInitExpression initialisedMember = Expression.MemberInit(objToInitialise, propertiesToInitialise);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(initialisedMember, parameter).Compile();
        }
    }

    public class Pupil
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
        private readonly SqliteConnection _connection;

        public SchoolContext(SqliteConnection connection, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
            _connection = connection;
        }

        public DbSet<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

            if (optionsBuilder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(optionsBuilder), "Options builder is required and cannot be null");
            }

            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(_connection)
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                    .UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            if (modelBuilder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilder), "Model builder is required and cannot be null");
            }

            modelBuilder.Entity<Pupil>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("pupil");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id)
                    .HasName("pupil_id_uindex")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("id")
                    .HasColumnType("char(36)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .HasColumnName("name")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(45)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Age)
                    .HasColumnName("age")
                    .HasColumnType("int(3)");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not filtering the columns. You are just enumerating through the class and taking every property.  You table has three columns id, name, and age.   What you are asking is to have multiple queries like 1) id and name 2) id and age 3) name and age 4) id, name, and age.

Comment: Ask yourself which `Select` extension method are you hitting with `Func<T, T>`. The answer is - `Enumerable.Select`, i.e. the query is retrieving the whole object from the database and then performs `Select` in memory.  Change the code to use  `Expression<Func<T, T>>` (remove `.Compile()` call inside) to hit `Queryable.Select` and everything will work as expected.

Comment: @IvanStoev That fixed it. Thanks very much. Feel free to drop an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev)

---

The issue was I was calling `Enumerable.Select` instead of `Queryable.Select`.

```
public Expression<Func<T, T>> Select()
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    NewExpression objToInitialise = Expression.New(typeof(T));
    IEnumerable<MemberAssignment> propertiesToInitialise = _properties.Select(property =>
        {
            MemberExpression originalValue = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
            return Expression.Bind(property, originalValue);
        }
    );
    MemberInitExpression initializedMember = Expression.MemberInit(objToInitialise, propertiesToInitialise);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(initializedMember, parameter);
}
```

By updating the `Selector.Select` method signature to the above, the correct select statement is used and it works as expected.